# F# - not understanding function composition (transform get files function to get duplicate files function)

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, composition

Here is my problem... I don't understand why this isn't working for me :)

To be more specific I have a get files function (not the problem but feedback is welcome):

```
type DirectoryOptions = Directory of string * Option<SearchOption>

type SearchOptions =
    | SearchSubDirectories
    | SearchCurrentDirectory

let WithExtensionIn extlist filename =
    let fileext = Path.GetExtension filename
    extlist |> Seq.exists (fun e -> e = fileext)

let GetFiles dir extlist =
    match dir with
        | Some diroptions ->
            let directoryname, suboptions = diroptions
            match suboptions with
                | Some SearchSubDirectories | None ->
                    Directory.GetFiles(directoryname, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    |> Seq.filter (WithExtensionIn extlist)
                | Some SearchCurrentDirectory ->
                    Directory.GetFiles(directoryname, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                    |> Seq.filter (WithExtensionIn extlist)
        | None ->
            Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    |> Seq.filter (WithExtensionIn extlist)
```

I want to compose this into a Get duplicate files function. I may not be able to but I am trying to get my head into the functional mindset. My current attempt, which based on my understanding should work, isn't working. This means that my understanding is wrong and I would like some help/clarification on how to solve this. My understanding is that in function composition the inner most function can have n input parameters but only one output and the remaining functions that wrap it can only have one in and one out. I'm not entirely sure how the first function is interpreted (might be a bad word to use) in the context of composition in F# because there is no distinct input/output. I believe this is the direct affect of currying.

Here is my current attempt:

```
let GetDuplicateFiles =
    let LengthAndExtension file =
        //this is faked for simplicity
        (12, ".htm")

    let GroupSizeGreaterThanOne group =
        let _, values = group
        Seq.length values > 1

    let content file =
        //again faked
        ()

    let groups items =
        snd items

    GetFiles
    >> Seq.groupBy LengthAndExtension
    >> Seq.filter GroupSizeGreaterThanOne
    >> Seq.collect groups
    >> Seq.groupBy content
    >> Seq.filter GroupSizeGreaterThanOne
    >> Seq.collect groups
```

This gives me a compile error on Seq.groupBy LengthAndExtension
the error is The type ''b -> seq' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'

Any thoughts/feedback is welcome. I think I'm looking for an ah ha moment if you know what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward-composition (`>>`) creates a new function, passing the output of the first as input to the second.

The signature reveals the problem: `( >> ) : ('T1 -> 'T2) -> ('T2 -> 'T3) -> 'T1 -> 'T3`

It accepts two functions each taking a single argument. But `GetFiles` takes two args. A quick solution is to change `GetFiles` to take a tuple: `let GetFiles (dir, extlist) = ...`.

Comment: Does that mean that F# function composition and mathematical composition vary slightly and the way to get F# to mimic the math is to wrap the n inputs into a tuple? Wierd but ok. My code works now, thank you.

Comment: Yes. The reason being that a function cannot have multiple return values. Tuples are the way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Using function composition `>>`, we have: `(f >> g) x = g(f(x))`. That means we apply `f` to the input first and apply `g` to the output after that.

An easy way to use function composition is writing the function using pipeline first and refactoring it later. I usually start with the form of `x |> f1 |> f2 |> ... |> fn`, remove the input `x` and change pipeline (`|>`) to function composition (`>>`) to have the correct composed function `f1 >> f2 >> ... >> fn`. However, it's not obvious in your example:

```
let GetDuplicateFiles(dir, extlist) =
    //...
    GetFiles dir extlist
    |> Seq.groupBy LengthAndExtension
    |> Seq.filter GroupSizeGreaterThanOne
    |> Seq.collect groups
    |> Seq.groupBy content
    |> Seq.filter GroupSizeGreaterThanOne
    |> Seq.collect groups
```

If you change `GetFiles` from the curried form of `GetFiles dir extlist` to the tuple form of `GetFiles(dir, extlist)`, you can easily apply the above trick to use function composition.

And on a side note, you can change `Seq.filter ... >> Seq.collect` to `Seq.choose ... >> Seq.concat` to save one time traverse through the sequence:

```
let GetDuplicateFiles =
    //...

// (dir, extlist)
// |>
    GetFiles
    >> Seq.groupBy LengthAndExtension
    >> Seq.choose GroupSizeGreaterThanOne
    >> Seq.concat
    >> Seq.groupBy content
    >> Seq.choose GroupSizeGreaterThanOne
    >> Seq.concat
```

The `GroupSizeGreaterThanOne` function is slightly changed:

```
let GroupSizeGreaterThanOne (_, values) =
    if Seq.length values > 1 then Some values else None
```

Comment: I think your code is cleaner but where is the traverse saved?

Comment: `Seq.collect` is basically `Seq.map` following by `Seq.concat`. By saving a traversal, I mean you could drop an unnecessary `Seq.map`.

Comment: Isn't Seq.collect the same as the monadic bind for sequences? Also aren't Seq.collect, Seq.map, Seq.concat all lazy meaning that I don't save a traverse of the sequence per se but I do save an extra call on the stack?